# NSOulineView alignment and header cell font

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I have specifically three problems with NSOulineView.

[image: My NSOutlineView]

1) Header Cells font: I want to reduce the font size just of the header cell. I tried using IB but without success. Unbinding the Table Cell View from the NSOutlineView does work but it is not really feasible if I want to further extend the number of groups in the outline view.

2) Header Cells alignment: the alignment of the header cells is not fixed but the text position changes if I resize the view (as you can see in the image). One solution is to add a new constraint (leading space to superview) to the Table Cell View. Is there any other better fix (programmatically)?

3) Vertical alignment: The icon and the text inside the row for the Cell is not centered vertically. Do I need to play with the Cell frame to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each point:

1) Problem solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383181/nsoulineview-header-cell-font)

2) Everything works fine if I disable the Auto Layout

3) Problem solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103125/vertically-aligning-text-in-nstableview-row)